# German children's story - Mutchi

Tags: resource, literature

I am looking for an old German story that talks about a boy called Mutchi, who  lives many adventures. The problem is I don't remember many details about the story. I know he takes a ride with a fish to get to the bottom of the ocean , he travels with an eagle through the sky, and then the night comes (and it is a woman dressed in black) and he starts asking for his mum. Soon after that the boy wakes up behind a bush and realises he had been dreaming all along. This is all I can remember. I really wanted to find this book for my grandma cause her mother used to read it to her ( in German, from a German book with children's stories). This took place in the early forties, so that means the book has got to be older than that. 
Anyone at all who can help me with that?

Comment: Die Frage wird kaum jemanden finden, der die gleiche Frage hat. Je nach Kürze des Titels wird sie zu Geschwafel führen, nur um die Länge auf das Mindestmaß auszudehnen. Der Schließgrund 'zu spezifisch' ist aber aus der Liste der Gründe entfernt worden - solche Fragen gehören allenfalls in den Chat, der wiederum eine höhere Reputation verlangt.

Comment: Are you really sure that it is a german story? *Mutchi* is not a German name. There is no German word that contains the sequence »tchi«.

Comment: @userunknown You could vote for story identification being off-topic, referring to [this Meta question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/734/do-we-want-to-allow-story-identification-questions). But I don't see a problem leaving this question open. In particular the _tch_ vs. _tsch_ problem could be of wider interest.

Comment: I am closing this question because [the community decided that story-identification questions are not on-topic](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/734/2594).

Answer (score 7):

The character sequence "tch" is rarely found in German words. The sound that English speakers would probably denote this way would rather be transcribed "tsch". So I changed *Mutchi* to *Mutschi*, and googling for "Mutschi Junge" I very quickly found the book [*Aus jüdischer Seele. Ausgewählte Werke*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Bj_ZvcQuE6AC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=mutschi+junge&source=bl&ots=ZMq6qQqR1Y&sig=mHottrWYrmr77twb_siYi3t1ZR8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIlfrc2OylyAIVRdIaCh262wkf#v=onepage&q=mutschi%20junge&f=false), which looks like it contains a story matching your description. Unfortunately, I cannot tell the title from the Google Books excerpt.

Credits go to [Loong](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9551/loong) for being smart enough to browse the book's table of contents and finding a nicely illustrated [PDF version](http://digital.ub.uni-paderborn.de/download/pdf/1173211?name=Mutschi) of the same story, which is by [Jakob Loewenberg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Loewenberg) and is simply called "Mutschi".

Comment: The sequence »tch« can only be found in German word if it is part of »tchen«, where »chen« is the diminutive suffix: »Brötchen«, »Bärtchen«, »Heftchen«. You can also find it in diminutive versions of names: »Gretchen«. But there is not a single german word where »tch« is followed by »i«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast So _Ostchile_ and _Westchile_ are not German words? Not to mention _Tchibo_? ;-)

Comment: Zumindest die Allesverkäuferei mit angeschossener Kaffeerösterei hätte ich spontan *Tschibo* geschrieben …;)

Comment: Since German words containing _tsch_ are not easy to be found either, I'd like to link here to one of the most fascinating words of my childhood: [Tschitscheringrün](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschitscheringr%C3%BCn).

Comment: @Jan Verständlich, aber da stand einst der Name _Tchiling_ Pate, der aus dem Armenischen stammt: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tchibo#Unternehmensgeschichte

Comment: @Matthias: Chile ist nicht wirklich ein deutsches Wort. Es ist ein Fremdwort, dass aus einer südamerikanischen Indianersprache stammt. Und die erste Silbe des Markennamens Tchibo geht auf den Familiennamen des armenisch-stämmigen Gründers Carl Tchilling-Hiryan zurück, ist also auch nicht wirklich deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke, aber das ist mir bekannt, wie Du zum Teil schon aus meinem vorigen Kommentar erkennen könntest. Interessant wäre hingegen Deine Definition von "wirklich deutsches Wort". Humor scheint für Dich ja auch ein Fremdwort zu sein.

Comment: @Matthias: Ob ein Wort, dass einer fremden Sprache entstammt, aber gängig ist und im Duden steht, tatsächlich ein deutsches Wort ist, kann Gegenstand einer längeren Diskussion sein. Mit dem Begriff »wirklich deutsches Wort« würde ich gerne ein Wort bezeichnen, das einen direkten etymologischen Vorgänger im Althochdeutschen hat. Das trifft weder auf *Chile* noch auf *Tschibo* zu. Übrigens: »*Humor*« ist tatsächlich ein Fremdwort. Es ist ein lateinisches Wort, das auf Deutsch »Feuchtigkeit« bedeutet. Ich bin eher ein Freund der trockenen *Feuchtigkeit*.

Comment: Oh my god! You guys are amazing! I am sorry if I posted at the wrong place or something. I appreciate everyone's effort.

Comment: I was almost giving up! I never thought of spelling Mutchi as Mutschi ! This is amazing. That is the correct story ! Danke schön!

Comment: Was ist mit Hatschi, kitschig, matschig?